# How to make my JQuery code work properly for multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to show and hide menu items on hover:

```
jQuery( "#menu-item-11215" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11215 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11215 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);

jQuery( "#menu-item-11233" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11233 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11233 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);

jQuery( "#menu-item-11211" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11211 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11211 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);

jQuery( "#menu-item-11268" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11268 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11268 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);

jQuery( "#menu-item-11243" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11243 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11243 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);

jQuery( "#menu-item-11239" ).hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11239 .sub-menu').show();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#menu-item-11239 .sub-menu').hide();
    }
);
```

Rather than repeat the same code over and over, is there a way to trigger the JQuery to work for any of the IDs that have a child ? Here is the relevant HTML code for just one of these. They are all set up the same way:

```
<ul class="fusion-megamenu fusion-megamenu-row-2 fusion-megamenu-row-columns-1 fusion-megamenu-border">
    <li id="menu-item-11215" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-11215 fusion-megamenu-submenu fusion-megamenu-columns-1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h3 class='fusion-megamenu-title'>
            <a href="http://someurl">Families &#038; Individuals</a>
        </h3>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-11275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11275">
                <a href="http://someurl">
                    <span class="fusion-megamenu-bullet"></span>Tax &#038; Advisory
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-11277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11277">
                <a href="http://someurl">
                    <span class="fusion-megamenu-bullet"></span>Trust &#038; Estates
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Knowing that the parent of each child has an ID and I can select the child to show and hide using this code:

```
jQuery('#menu-item-11211 .sub-menu')
```

How can I make this more generic to save lines of code?

Comment: This is the point of classes, change all the `#menu-item-#####` to just a class `.menu-item`, and have a single `hover` event using `this` for the item you are on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce everything you have to:

```
jQuery( "ul.fusion-megamenu > li" ).hover(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').show();
    },
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
    }
);
```

By using `jQuery(this).find()` you only search the list relative to the list you hover over.

Comment: This is the best solution I have seen to this question because it doesn't require anything else to work other than the "ul.fusion-megamenu > li" statement. Can you explain to me what that statement is doing exactly?

Comment: Sure, it selects only the list elements that are children (not any descendant, only children list items) of the list with the class fusion-megamenu. I could have made it super-specific and used `ul.fusion-megamenu.fusion-megamenu-row-2.fusion-megamenu-row-columns-1.fusion-megamenu-border` but I thought that it might have been overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector: `$('[id^="menu-item"]')` to act on every item that has `ID` starting with `menu-item`.

In your function it would be `$('.sub-menu',this)`

```
jQuery('[id^="menu-item"]').hover(
    function() {
        jQuery('.sub-menu',this).show(); // <--- this selects .sub-menu with parent of menu-item it is reffering to.
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('.sub-menu',this).hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to find each element based on the id's then put them in a comma separated string like below

```js
menuitems = "#menu-item-11215, #menu-item-11233";
jQuery( menuitems ).hover(
          function(){
              $(this).children(".sub-menu").show();
          },
          function(){
              $(this).children(".sub-menu").hide();
          }
        );
```

I've used .children because it should be faster than .find, but it will only search the immediate children of your menu-items and won't go any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to refactor this code in order to reduce duplication. Most of them have nothing to do with jQuery but with the JavaScript langauge itself. For example:

```
var itemNumbers = [
    "11215",
    "11233",
    "11211",
    "11268",
    "11243",
    "11239"
];

for(var i=0; i<itemNumbers.length; i++){
    var menuItem = jQuery("#menu-item-" + itemNumbers[i]);
    var subMenu = menuItem.find(".sub-menu");
    menuItem.hover(subMenu.show, subMenu.hide);
}
```

or:

```
var itemNumbers = [
    "11215",
    "11233",
    "11211",
    "11268",
    "11243",
    "11239"
];

var menuItems = $();
for(var i=0; i<itemNumbers.length; i++){
    menuItems = menuItems.add("#menu-item-" + itemNumbers[i]);
}

menuItems.hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are missing a few quotes.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Tanks. I forgot some commas as well.

Answer (score -1):

then just pass-in the elements in `elm` and what set would be `show` or `hide`

```
   function MyToggle(elm,set){
      if(set=="show"){
        $(elm+' .sub-menu').show();
      }else{//hide
        $(elm+' .sub-menu').hide();
      }
    }
```